# Gerar .exe a partir do meu Programa

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, compiladores, delphi-10, projeto-de-compiladores

Bom estou em duvida vi em um fórum algo a respeito sobre isso [Conteúdo achado no fórum](https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/112651-gerar-exe-apartir-de-outro-exe/) e estou a procura de mais explicações  e exemplos

Estou a desenvolver um Auto-Backup de Banco de dados gerando seu arquivo .SQL e compactando em um arquivo .zip ou .rar, minha duvida é o seguinte queria criar um executável no qual ele ira encapsular o arquivo .zip ou .rar para dentro dele, exemplos de encapsulamento de arquivos em um executável encontrados [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/resources-no-delphi-como-embutir-arquivos-no-executavel/36874) , eu sei também que tem como fazer esse encapsulamento via código no Delphi construindo o código e passando o local do arquivo e também sei que o Delphi permite compilar manualmente.

Exemplo do que eu quero e tipo o [Winrar](http://www.winrarbrasil.com.br/winrar/index.mv) que gera um Arquivo.rar de sua extensão que é aberto em seu software e com possível proteção de senha.

Explicações: Quero fazer um executável a partir do meu para encapsular um arquivo pois assim o arquivo só poderá ser aberto por esse executável gerado criando assim algumas personalizações do tipo colocar senha no executável assim protegendo o arquivo.

Comment: O que você precisa é colocar a extensão do arquivo no registro do `windows` e criptografar o conteúdo do arquivo para que outro programa ou outra pessoal não consiga identificar.

Comment: Questão de colocar a extensão no registro do windows eu já estava estudando porem como criptografar o conteúdo do arquivo sem corromper ele e ainda fazendo com que somente meu software abra ele

Comment: Para ser mais claro seria criar um Winrar da vida onde ele é um Executável no qual gera outro executável com arquivos dentro desse

Comment: Sua descrição esta um pouco confusa. Me parece que você quer que seu programa criptografe os arquivos de backup, e que somente ele consiga descompacta-los. Seria isto? Se sim, existe uma vasta gama de bibliotecas de criptografia que você pode utilizar para este desenvolvimento, ex: DCPCrypt

Comment: Isso assim somente meu programa poderia abrir o arquivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme conversamos nos comentários, estou passando como utilizo a biblioteca [DCPCrypt](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/dcpcrypt/) para [criptografar/descriptografar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptografia) arquivos. Esta pode ser utilizada como componente no delphi, é gratuito e open source.

Criptografar/descriptografar arquivo:

```
uses
  DCPcrypt2, System.Math, DCPsha512, DCPdes;

procedure EncriptaArquivo(aArquivo: string; aArquivoEncriptado: string; aHash: TDCP_hash; aCipher: TDCP_cipher; aSenha: String);
var
  CipherIV: array of byte;
  HashDigest: array of byte;
  Salt: array[0..7] of byte;
  strmInput, strmOutput: TFileStream;
  i: integer;
begin
  strmInput := nil;
  strmOutput := nil;
  try
    strmInput := TFileStream.Create(aArquivo,fmOpenRead);
    strmOutput := TFileStream.Create(aArquivoEncriptado,fmCreate);

    SetLength(HashDigest,aHash.HashSize div 8);
    for i := 0 to 7 do
      Salt[i] := Random(256);
    strmOutput.WriteBuffer(Salt,Sizeof(Salt));
    aHash.Init;
    aHash.Update(Salt[0],Sizeof(Salt));
    aHash.UpdateStr(aSenha);
    aHash.Final(HashDigest[0]);

    if (aCipher is TDCP_blockcipher) then
    begin
      SetLength(CipherIV,TDCP_blockcipher(aCipher).BlockSize div 8);
      for i := 0 to (Length(CipherIV) - 1) do
        CipherIV[i] := Random(256);
      strmOutput.WriteBuffer(CipherIV[0],Length(CipherIV));
      aCipher.Init(HashDigest[0],System.Math.Min(aCipher.MaxKeySize,aHash.HashSize),CipherIV);
      TDCP_blockcipher(aCipher).CipherMode := cmCBC;
    end
    else
      aCipher.Init(HashDigest[0],Min(aCipher.MaxKeySize,aHash.HashSize),nil);

    aCipher.EncryptStream(strmInput,strmOutput,strmInput.Size);
    aCipher.Burn;
    strmInput.Free;
    strmOutput.Free;
  except
    strmInput.Free;
    strmOutput.Free;
    MessageDlg('Um erro aconteceu no processo de encriptação',mtError,[mbOK],0);
  end;
end;


procedure DesencriptaArquivo(aArquivoEncriptado: string; aArquivoDesencriptado: string; aHash: TDCP_hash; aCipher: TDCP_cipher; aSenha: String);
var
  CipherIV: array of byte;
  HashDigest: array of byte;
  Salt: array[0..7] of byte;
  strmInput, strmOutput: TFileStream;
begin
  strmInput := nil;
  strmOutput := nil;
  try
    strmInput := TFileStream.Create(aArquivoEncriptado,fmOpenRead);
    strmOutput := TFileStream.Create(aArquivoDesencriptado,fmCreate);

    SetLength(HashDigest,aHash.HashSize div 8);
    strmInput.ReadBuffer(Salt[0],Sizeof(Salt));
    aHash.Init;
    aHash.Update(Salt[0],Sizeof(Salt));
    aHash.UpdateStr(aSenha);
    aHash.Final(HashDigest[0]);

    if (aCipher is TDCP_blockcipher) then
    begin
      SetLength(CipherIV,TDCP_blockcipher(aCipher).BlockSize div 8);
      strmInput.ReadBuffer(CipherIV[0],Length(CipherIV));
      aCipher.Init(HashDigest[0],Min(aCipher.MaxKeySize,aHash.HashSize),CipherIV);
      TDCP_blockcipher(aCipher).CipherMode := cmCBC;
    end
    else
      aCipher.Init(HashDigest[0],Min(aCipher.MaxKeySize,aHash.HashSize),nil);

    aCipher.DecryptStream(strmInput,strmOutput,strmInput.Size - strmInput.Position);
    aCipher.Burn;
    strmInput.Free;
    strmOutput.Free;
  except
    strmInput.Free;
    strmOutput.Free;
    MessageDlg('Um erro aconteceu no processo de desencriptação',mtError,[mbOK],0);
  end;
end;
```

Exemplo encriptação:

```
var
  vHash: TDCP_hash;
  vCipher: TDCP_3des;
  vSenha: String;
begin
  vSenha := 'abobrinha123';
  vHash := TDCP_sha512.Create(nil);
  vCipher := TDCP_3des.Create(nil);
  try
    EncriptaArquivo('d:\ArquivoOriginal.txt', 'd:\ArquivoEncriptado.txt', vHash, vCipher, vSenha);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vHash);
    FreeAndNil(vCipher);
  end;
end;
```

Exemplo desencriptação:

```
var
  vHash: TDCP_hash;
  vCipher: TDCP_3des;
  vSenha: String;
begin
  vSenha := 'abobrinha123';
  vHash := TDCP_sha512.Create(nil);
  vCipher := TDCP_3des.Create(nil);
  try
    DesencriptaArquivo('d:\ArquivoEncriptado.txt', 'd:\ArquivoDesencriptado.txt', vHash, vCipher, vSenha);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(vHash);
    FreeAndNil(vCipher);
  end;

end;
```

No exemplo utilizei o algoritmo de hash [sha-512](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) e cifra [3DES](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES), mas esta biblioteca tem uma vasta gama de opções de algoritmos, você pode utilizar o que você preferir.

No exemplo utilizei um arquivo txt pra facilitar o exemplo, mas este código funciona para qualquer tipo de arquivo.

Este exemplo foi criado utilizando os demos e documentação oficias do dcpcrypt.

Comment: Genial muito Obrigado, vai me ajudar muito, essa sua explicação mais exemplo vai ser uma mão na roda Valeu ai.